# Hiding the terminal tab in Visual studio code debugger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Trying to write something in python on Visual studio code and every time I run a debug it displays the terminal tab instead of the debug console tab, any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

When debugging python in Visual Studio Code, the place where the debug output is printed is defined by the `console` setting in your workspace's `.vscode/launch.json` file.

As can be seen [in the documentation for python debugging in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), specifically in [the console section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console), the default value for this is `"integratedTerminal"`.

If you would like to override this, simply set the value to `"none"` in `launch.json`.

Comment: I've done this and it's still outputting to the terminal which has baffled me, any ideas why this hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to your launch.json and set "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart".  This attribute should go in the configuration that you're currently using for debug, it's listed next to the green play button when debugging mode is selected. The attribute was specifically created for the purpose of displaying the debug console by default after debugging. My launch.json display:
[image]

That's also where you'll put the "console": "none" attribute if you go that route. You could do both for good measure: My launch.json display with both attributes:
[image]